# .bashrc environment variables not picked up by Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, variables, environment, configuration-files

I've added a few environment variables to my `.bashrc` file, some of these are paths to customized bin/programs, such as:

`export MY_ENV_PATH_VAR=/home/user/path/to/bin`

I've refreshed spacemacs' `.spacemacs.env` file by running `SPC f e E`, however these new variables in my `.bashrc` are not being included in `.spacemacs.env`.

The beginning of the `.spacemacs.env` file points out that variables which names match `spacemacs-ignored-environment-variables` will not be included, however, I don't know how/where to check these regexps.

I've tried to go around this problem by adding the variables directly to the `spacemacs.env` file and this seems to work sporadically, sometimes the variables are picked up and sometimes they're not and I get errors such as `(Spacemacs) Error in dotspacemacs/user-env: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`

In my case, I'm calling `(add-to-list 'exec-path (getenv "MY_ENV_PATH_VAR"))` from `dotspacemacs/user-config` function.

Comment: What happens if you just restart emacs?

Comment: Whenever I restart I get the sporadic error of `(Spacemacs) Error in dotspacemacs/user-env: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`. Sometimes it shows and sometimes it works and the variables are picked up. The error showing up is more common though.

Comment: For now I've worked around this by just adding my variables directly into the `.spacemacs.env` file, that seems to work. I'd love for these to just leave in my `.bashrc` file though and Spacemacs get them from there.

Comment: What happens if you have no .spacemacs.env - also what OS are you running?

Comment: @mmmmmm the .spacemacs.env file is just re-created when I start emacs/emacsclient again. I'm running Ubuntu 22.04